# cannot change null to not null

Tags: sql

The column name on table `[dbo].[payment_info]` must be changed from **NULL** to **NOT NULL**. If the table contains data, the **ALTER** script may not work. 
To avoid this issue, you must add values to this column for all rows or mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payment_info]
 (
    [name]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [card_no]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [card_type] VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [tel_no]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [mob_no]    VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [address]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
```

I cannot change `NULL`to `NOT NULL`; when I update it's showing the above warning.

I am using visual studio 2013 asp.net and c#.

Comment: Does the table already exist?

Comment: yes...in this its given null but i need to change everything to not null..after changing to not null i cannot update database(i.e save the database)

Comment: "To avoid this issue, you must add values to this column for all rows or mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option." The message itself gives you the answer....

Comment: Well that's your issue, when the table already exists you can not ***CREATE*** it, as well... that would create something that already exists. You want to be `ALTER`ing it.

Comment: If you actually read the words in the error message, it explains quite clearly what the problem is and how to fix it. Learn to read those words - they're not there just to show something on you screen. They actually contain information, but you have to actually read them to get that info.

Answer (score 2):

If table already exists and is fulfilled with data, you have to update all NULLs in column you want to change on some value which is not NULL. Then ALTER command should work wthout warnings and/or errors.

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dataconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constr);

            SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand("insert into payment_info(name,card_no,tel_no, mob_no, address) values('" + name + "','"+ cno + "','"+ tno +"','"+ mbno +"', '"+ address + "')", cn);

Comment: if(ddlcardtype.SelectedValue =="1")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into payment_info(card_type) values('" + ddlcardtype.SelectedItem  +"')", cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();

            }

Comment: else if(ddlcardtype.SelectedValue =="2")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into payment_info(card_type) values('" + ddlcardtype.SelectedItem  + "')", cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();

            }

Comment: these are my coding part...sorry to send like this

Comment: @user2123496 you can update your question, makes reading easier. But the main problem is that the query `insert into payment_info(card_type) ...` is not possible.

Comment: @user2123496 you can just use UPDATE statement with WHERE clause set to NULL. all columns in your table are VARCHAR so please update NULLs to one white space character or empty string. I don't know if you have any other structures like relations between tables (something can work not properly), but for your task it is enough

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I understood your problem correctly, but the warning says it all - you can't switch column to not nullable, if there are nulls already in the column.

You have to update and set some values to empty entries or set DEFAULT value

**EDIT**:

You should try first:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[payment_info] 
where name is null
```

and check if there are any problems

Comment: but i need the values to be saved into database when i click the button...among this only card_type is being saved into the table

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your table in server explorer and click "new query". Type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE
  table
ALTER COLUMN
  column
    int NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced by **SSDT**. This will happen if you have an existing table and you would like to add a new **non-nullable** column to it. In order to do so, you must have a default for this new column (the default can be some temporary value).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payment_info]
 (
    [WhateverColumn] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Foo',
    -- and so on
);
```

If you want to change the default to a more meaningful value, you can write the script to update the table and set the column's value to a more meaningful value in a post deployment. In post deployment you can also now drop the default since it was temporary:

```
ALTER TABLE WhateverTable
ALTER COLUMN WhateverColumn DROP DEFAULT;
```

Now your deployment will succeed.

**Note**: If your column is a foreign-key column, the default has to exist in the parent table even if the value is temporary.